# twitter bootstrap buttons look funny on chrome and are grey on FF

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using a lot of bootstrap features on my website (ASP.NET) and they all work fine.
But when I add a button it looks funny:
[image: I added an image for your viewing pleasure.]

This is the tag:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCheck" runat="server" Text="Bla" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="btnCheck_Click" />
```

FF looks weird as well:
[image]

I made sure that all the links to the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js are OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? When you inspect the button in Chrome, what other CSS is applied?

Comment: Did you check the applied classes with FireBug or anything like that? Also you can trace down the css rules, which are responsible for the layout with this.

Comment: The first thing to do is rule out CSS conflicts with other CSS frameworks that you have on your site. Have you tried using Google Chrome's built-in web inspector or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to rule out what else is effecting that element? Do you have a URL?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the fast reply. I'm using Chrome's web inspector and i haven't seen any conflicts.. This is the the rendered HTML: '<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCheck" value="bla" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCheck&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCheck" class="btn btn-success">'

Comment: @Zach I even excluded the whole CSS and just left the bootstrap CSS and it still didn't work.

Comment: Hi - well, see that's going to be the tricky thing. First thing to do is check the demo site - look fine there? Great. Your site isn't as you're saying with the "exact" same setup, but unfortunately, the difference is the part that's causing the issue. If you have a URL, I could take a look, but otherwise, will be a stab in the dark.

Comment: I would send a link but it's on my local machine for now. I tried something else, I made a new aspx page in the same project which is not connected to the master page and it's linked only to the bootstrap css file, but still no go. I even tried making an HTML page (not aspx).

Comment: Where did you get the twitter bootstrap CSS from? Is it the full version or did you get a custom version?

Comment: It's the full version I downloaded from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: I noticed that the icon feature in bootstrap doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I used an old version of bootstrap and it was updated to 2.1.1 , I downloaded the new version and everything looks good. Thanks for the help!